# My app keeps crashing after i changed my dependenciess

Tags: java, android-studio

So my problem in the start was  very similar to the problem here
[Error in Android Studio while updating location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037777/error-in-android-studio-while-updating-location)
and then I  changed my dependencies .....but now my app crashes when i try to press the button to open the map

These are my dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

}
```

and this is the Mappage I made

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.example.delivery_app.databinding.ActivityMapsDriverBinding;

public class MapsActivityDriver extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsDriverBinding binding;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiclient;
    Location mLastlocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationrequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsDriverBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        buildGoogleapiclient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleapiclient() {
        mGoogleApiclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiclient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        mLastlocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationrequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationrequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationrequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiclient, mLocationrequest, this);
    }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended ( int i){

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed (@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult){

        }

    }
```

*edit
so i checked my logcat
and i saw this  "java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" and bunch of location where i shld give access(it mostly gave me gradles)  but I  wrote  in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: The first step to debugging a crash it to look at the Logcat tab in Android Studio and find the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: i saw logcat and it said "java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
and bunch of location where i shld  
but i remember writing in manifest 
```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    ```
@Code-Apprentice